# Lucene index broken

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, compass-lucene

I am having some issues with lucene index. This happened in the past and I re-indexed the whole data and it has happened again.

Indeed that file is missing in the folder I do not know how it has dissapeared.
Would be possible to recover the index going back to a older status without deleting everything?
[image: file _3npk.cfs missing]

```
Caused by: org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to open Lucene reader/searcher; nested exception is org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to open index searcher for sub-index [ctadoc]; nested exception is org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to open sub index cache [ctadoc]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /fs/eudract/eudract_ps_index/index/ctadoc/_3npk.cfs (No such file or directory)
```

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards

Comment: Which version of Lucene?

Comment: the version of Lucene in my application is 2.4.1

Comment: FYI, https://www.cmswire.com/cms/enterprise-cms/apache-lucenesolr-340-released-brings-improved-indexing-faster-search-bug-fixes-012713.php  Lucene 3.4.0 also comes with various bug fixes .... For instance, a major bug that results in corrupted indexes with power losses is now fixed.